# Passing a constant or parameter to the data-bind click function in KO.js

Tags: knockout.js

I want to implement a menu. Each button in menu should set the menu ID in the model. I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
     data-bind="click:selectUi('menu'),visible:sessionId()!=''">
  Menu
</a>
```

Instead the selectUi is called when the page loads.

The only possible solution which comes right now to my mind is to implement  one function for each button. Is that the right way?

Comment: @michael is right use `.bind` at the end and pass parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your function call in a function.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
     data-bind="click:function () { selectUi('menu'); },visible:sessionId()!=''">
  Menu
</a>
```

You could also make `selectUi` return a function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) plugin, this is easy:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
     data-bind="on.click: selectUi('menu'), visible: sessionId()!=''">Menu</a>
```

Without the plugin, you could use an anonymous function or `bind`:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
     data-bind="click: selectUi.bind($data, 'menu'), visible: sessionId()!=''">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Punches. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just for mentioning one possible solution, which I've used before applying the answer of Roy J.

Use the functions without parameters.

e.g:

```
<a data-bind="click:selectUi_menu"> Menu </a>
```